# Is BTCfree.win scamming?

Tags: fraud

As I asked earlier, I have two email accounts in BTCfree.win, and I achieved 0.2 free bitcoin over 3 years. On 24th September, I withdrew my bitcoin to my trust wallet address. It took about one month from my request for bitcoin withdrawal in withdrawal process. I was seeing the process from the start to pending to the next steps, but after one month, suddenly I didn't see the process in my profile. Now it is about one month more that I am waiting to receiving my bitcoins to my trust wallet, but unfortunately nothing happened and I don't know what shall I do. Please help me. My emails are: [*personally identifiable information removed*]

Why you answered that I must not to believe the BTCfree.win? And why you closed my question too soon. The site introduced you as a responsible place to answer our questions! So how you said that it was wrong that I believe them?

Please send my 0.2 bitcoin for each of my accounts to my trust wallet as soon as possible.
If you don't pay my 0.4 bitcoins to my trust wallet, I will complain about you and also BTCfree.win all around the world.

I am looking forward to hearing from you. Regards, Tahereh

Comment: Very very interesting. No one responsible.  No one can withdraw their money. Digital coins are scams.

Answer (score 3):

I think what is happening is the following:
BTCfree•win is earning advertisement revenue from their visitors’ attention (or something similar). They use promises of "free bitcoin" to make people visit their site over and over again, but the promised "free bitcoins" don’t exist, so they never pay out anything. They appear to be wasting your time for their own profit.

Our website is a Question and Answer platform for Bitcoin enthusiasts to discuss the Bitcoin technology and its applications. There is no relationship between BTCfree•win and our website. The people lying to you about "free bitcoins" are also lying to you about us being "responsible to answer their customers' questions". We are just a community of random people on the internet that is interested in Bitcoin. We don’t have any insights into the internal processes of the scam you are victim to, and we don’t control the funds that you expect to receive.

I can only encourage you to complain about BTCfree•win all across the internet. I would also suggest that you report the fraud to your local police.
You could of course also complain about us, but our only "connection" to BTCfree•win is that they are trying to redirect their angry users at us.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I understand it. Unfortunately, the BT free.win introduced you for our questions. Anyway thanks

Comment: You are welcome, thanks for taking your time to read my comment